# Test mouseOut/un hover in RTL / Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Trying to test mouseOut / un hover element in Jest/RTL:

So far I have:

```
it('Should test tooltip', async () => {
    render(<Tooltip />);
    fireEvent.mouseOver(screen.getByTestId('tooltip-icon'));
    await waitFor(() => screen.getByTestId('tooltip-info'))
    expect(screen.getByText("'Information'")).toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.mouseOut(screen.getByTestId('tooltip-icon'));
    await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.getByTestId('tooltip-info'))
    expect(screen.getByText("'Information'")).not.toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

But I do get the error `TypeError: currentDocument.elementFromPoint is not a function`

My mouse events are:

```
    <span onMouseOver={(event: any) => tooltip.current && tooltip.current.handleMouseOver(event)}
          onMouseOut={(event) => tooltip.current && tooltip.current.handleMouseOut(event)}>
     <img src='xxx' data-testid='info-icon'/>
    </span>
```

Any Idea's?

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You mean a codeSandbox or something?

Comment: Your component code can't run. Please provide minimal, complete, runnable code